# Calling JQuery function inside repeater

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

call jquery function inside repeater.the problem  i want to toggle the div when click on the linkbutton .i think not first jquery function use with this case . 
i think also the probelem from the table between div and link button .

```js
function toggleMe() {
        $(function () {
            $('.toggler').on('click', function (ev) {
                $(this).next('.dataContentSection').toggle();
            });
        });
        }
```

```html
<div id="repeater"><div class="dataContentSection">
    <div>Name</div>
</div>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                  <asp:LinkButton  class="titleText toggler" OnClientClick="javascript:toggleMe(); return false;"  runat="server">+ Address details</asp:LinkButton>

                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Welcome"></asp:Label>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<div class="dataContentSection" style="display: none;">
    <div>Address Line 1:</div>
    <div>Address Line 2:</div>
    <div>Address Line 3:</div>
</div>
<div class="dataContentSection">
    <div>Name</div>
</div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                  <asp:LinkButton  class="titleText toggler" OnClientClick="javascript:toggleMe(); return false;"  runat="server">+ Address details</asp:LinkButton>

                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Welcome"></asp:Label>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<div class="dataContentSection" style="display: none;">
    <div>Address Line 1:</div>
    <div>Address Line 2:</div>
    <div>Address Line 3:</div>
</div>
<div class="dataContentSection">
    <div>Name</div>
</div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                  <asp:LinkButton  class="titleText toggler" OnClientClick="javascript:toggleMe(); return false;"  runat="server">+ Address details</asp:LinkButton>

                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Welcome"></asp:Label>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<div class="dataContentSection" style="display: none;">
    <div>Address Line 1:</div>
    <div>Address Line 2:</div>
    <div>Address Line 3:</div>
</div>
<div class="dataContentSection">
    <div>Name</div>
</div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                  <asp:LinkButton  class="titleText toggler" OnClientClick="javascript:toggleMe(); return false;"  runat="server">+ Address details</asp:LinkButton>

                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Welcome"></asp:Label>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<div class="dataContentSection" style="display: none;">
    <div>Address Line 1:</div>
    <div>Address Line 2:</div>
    <div>Address Line 3:</div>
</div>
<div class="dataContentSection">
    <div>Name</div>
</div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                  <asp:LinkButton  class="titleText toggler" OnClientClick="javascript:toggleMe(); return false;"  runat="server">+ Address details</asp:LinkButton>

                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Welcome"></asp:Label>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<div class="dataContentSection" style="display: none;">
    <div>Address Line 1:</div>
    <div>Address Line 2:</div>
    <div>Address Line 3:</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what you want to achieve ? When I click on `Address Details` the link should open ? Please give us the details properly

Comment: when i click on linkbutton open the div.

Comment: @boshkash: Can you provide the CSS also of `dataContentSection`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was `toggleMe()` function.
IF you want the toggling of the div, you need to do something like this:-

```
  $(function () {
        $('.toggler').click(function (ev) {
            $(".dataContentSection").toggle();
            $(this).next('.dataContentSection').toggle();
        });
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: and what i do in onclientclick event button

Comment: I think you don't need that.It is working `onClick` of the button

Comment: because the post back open all div's

Comment: So do you want to open one div at a time ?

Comment: when i click button all div's open and close the reason is postback .i think

Comment: @boshkash: You can do with giving `ID` to the div and calling something like this `$(this).next('#div_ID').toggle();`